# How to define a good value for wal_keep_size parameter

Tags: postgresql

wal_keep_size (new in v.13) parameter specifies the minimum size of past log file segments kept in the pg_wal directory. How to set an appropriate value for this parameter?

Comment: Do you use streaming or logical replication?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: physical replication is configured with streaming mode.  The idea is to avoid this type of error after cloning a physical standby. ERROR:  requested WAL "segment ... has already been removed"

Answer (score 0):

It is not really new.  Before v13, it was called wal_keep_segments. It was counted in different units, but did the same thing.  But generally you should be using slots instead.  If you do need to use wal_keep_size rather than slots for some reason, then that reason (unknown to us) should determine what to set it to.

Comment: What does it mean to "use slots instead"?